# Project file was unloaded error when making a local copy of production site

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

The site uses ASP.NET Web Forms and I made a local copy of the production site. When I open the solution, it says "The project file 'c:\Users\path\path\path' has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer". I believe it is there, since I manually copied the entire folder onto my local machine. I have tried reloading project, and searched online but nothing works.

It says the same thing when I load the production solution file, but instead of "unloaded" it says "load failed".

I'm using VS 2019 pro, if that helps.

Comment: From where did you get the production site copy? What files does it have?

Comment: @Chetan I'm not 100% sure, but I was given a network path and the files are all under Network in file explorer. It contains all the files for the production web site.

Comment: You can try to delete .suo file. Then, you need re-open Visual Studio and re-add your project in the Visual Studio.

About path of .suo, Such as i have a project named Me. Its path of .suo is

Me => .vs(hidden file folder) => Me => v17

Answer (score 0):

It may well depend on the publish model used.

If that was a web site application, then all of the important source code files, the project file, and MORE will be missing.

As a result, you really don't have a working project.

You could try opening the folder as a web site as opposed to opening as a web site. However, before you do that, open up that folder, do you have the source code files (vb, or "cs" for c#).

So, unless the source code files are in that folder, then you don't have a working project. This is much like saying you have a .exe file, but don't have the source code used to build that .exe file!!

Either way, you need to get your hands on the source code project used to compile + build the project, and the published folder will in fact be of little use here if this was a "applicaton".

In a web site application, all source code files are compiled into a .dll, and the source code files are removed during the publish process. The end result is  JUST .aspx files with markup, but they are of little use if the code behind files are not in that folder.

It is possbile that a web site (as opposed to web site "application) was used here, and in that case, you WILL find the source code files in that folder.

If you do see/have the source code files (and also the aspx files), then you don't open that folder as a project, but must use

file->open web site, and that will allow you to browse to the folder.

As noted, you can spend all of 10 seconds, and take a look in the folder, and if you see BOTH .aspx files, and each form has a corresponding .cs (or .vb) file, then you in good shape. If the source code files are not in that folder, then you will need to get your hands on the source code project used to build + compile that project.